# Vue component method not being run on event in dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I am attempting to dynamically create some HTML content and bind a Vue component method to an event on the element. However this does not work. Below is a description of the problem and a snippet with a test case.

## Steps to reproduce problem

1. Click **Click me 1**
2. Observe the console.
3. Click **Toggle popover for tooltip**.
4. Click **Click me 2**
5. Observe the console.

## Expected behaviour

In Step 2 you should see *"you should see this in the console"* in the console. In Step 5 you should see *"you should see this in the console"* again.

## Actual behaviour

In Step 2, *"you should see this in the console"* appears in the console. In Step 5, *"you should see this in the console"* does not appear in the console.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    expectToSucceed() {
      console.log('you should see this in the console');
    },
  },

  created() {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      const mockedDynamicHtml = `
        <div class="popover">
          <h1>Example tooltip</h1>
          <button @click="expectToSucceed" class="remove">Click me 2</button>
        </div>
      `;

      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        template: mockedDynamicHtml,
      });
    });
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover for tooltip</a>
      <br><br>
      <p><span @click="expectToSucceed">Click me 1</span></p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is this 'somewhere dynamically'? Please, show the whole code, because it matters.

Comment: I updated my answer with `Fiddle`

Comment: I have more experience with Angular than with Vue, but this design problem is widely known in Angular realm and basically falls into 'don't use jQuery with ...' category. There's no way to bind it like that, and the question is XY problem. If you're interested in a solution that is idiomatic to Vue, I would suggest to ask a new question that addresses the problem directly. It will probably require to have 2 components instead of one.

Comment: You are right.I will try with 2 components and i hope it will work.thanks @estus

Answer (score 1):

It will be `@click`, like this:

```
<i @click="test"></i>
```

as shorthand of [v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) is `@` not `:`.

Comment: Thanks for correction it was my mistake `:` instead of `@` but problem is same.It's working with `@` also.

Comment: Kindly read my reply on your answer.It's not working as well.

Comment: I am using this click event  inside `ES6 template string`.

Comment: @TheUnknown How are you appending `htmlCotent ` string, can you add that in a fiddle.

Comment: Ya sure i will make fiddle that would be more easy to understand.

Comment: here is like link for fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/arifhussain/txhk1k24/1/

Comment: @TheUnknown I think jquery is not binding the click event and method properly, An sample modal implementation with Vue is provided [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html), in the meanwhile I will try to make this work.

Comment: ya and in your provided `vuejs` link there done this similar task with difference component.We need 2 component to achieve this task.I will also try this.Thank you so much @Saurabh