# Vue js 2 Method not working from click event

Tags: components, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue component` which prints out a list of radio buttons. I have a `watch` on `internalValue` which sends the selected value to the `root`

I am trying to send a `console.log` on a `click event` using a `method` called `doSomething` but it is not working. Furthermore I am not getting any errors or warnings.

**Load Component**

```
Vue.component('topic', require('./components/Topicselect.vue'));
```

**Use Component**

```
<div class="form-group" id="topic">
    <topic v-model="selectedTopic"></topic>
</div>
```

**Initialise Vue**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#topic',
    data: {
      selectedTopic: null
    }
});
```

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-for="topic in topics" class="radio-inline radio-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('http://s3.hubsrv.com/trendsideas.com/profiles/74046767539/photo/3941785781469144249_690x460.jpg')">
      <input type="radio" v-model="internalValue" :click="doSomething" name="topics_radio" :id="topic.id" :value="topic.name">
      <span class="white-color lg-text font-regular text-center text-capitalize">{{ topic.name }}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      internalValue: this.value,
      topics: []
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get('/vuetopics').then(response => this.topics = response.data);
  },
  watch: {
    internalValue(v){
      this.$emit('input', v);
      console.log('the value is ' + this.value);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething: function (){
      console.log('doSomething is firing');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try `@click` instead of `:click`

Comment: Doh, thanks, that solves it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue component method not being run on event in dynamic HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761557/vue-component-method-not-being-run-on-event-in-dynamic-html)

Comment: instead of @click you can also use v-on:click=